# Can not change the property of an object after initial binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I got stuck on a problem. In the project I am working on I have to populate one column of ListView with cheboxes and another one with comboboxes. The following is the data model that I am using as an ObservableCollection to bind it to a listview. Works really well!

```
public class PointDataMainListView

{
    public string CheckBoxName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxItems{ get; set; }
    public Visibility visibility { get; set; }
}
```

Except I have a hard time changing the properties of the combobox itself. In particular the visibility property.

The following is the data template i am using for the combo box

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxCell">

        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
                  Width="100"
                  Visibility="{Binding visibility}"/>

    </DataTemplate>
```

When populating the listview for the first time or adding a new item to a listview visibility could be set no problem. When visibility inside my ObservableCollection < PointDataMainListView >  is changed for the item already displayed nothing is happening.

One of the solution I was looking into is trying to itterate through a list view items to try and get a reference to the actual combobox to change it's property. That said, I believe there must be a more elegant solution to achieve the desired results. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want to set visibility to all comboboxes? perhaps make a grid and bind to grid visibility instead. so all comboboxes are displayed or hidden.

Comment: I want to be able to set the visibility of each combobox individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and your properties setters need to invoke the PropertyChanged method.